# how to serialize json when the value changes from int to array + order may change

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm not sure how to serialize the following example from json to a c# object. Normally, I do something like this:

```
 JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 result = ser.Deserialize<Library.Libraries.Model.Post>(responseFromServer);
```

But in this case, I'm not sure how to create the class to base it off since the values and order might change.

Here's the example:

```
    {
       "data": [
          {
             "id": "0000000/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day",
             "name": "page_fan_adds_unique",
             "period": "day",
             "values": [
                {
                   "value": 2,
                   "end_time": "2010-09-15T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                   "value": 0,
                   "end_time": "2010-09-16T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                   "value": 1,
                   "end_time": "2010-09-17T07:00:00+0000"
                }
             ],
             "description": "Daily New Likes of your Page (Unique Users)"
          },
          {
             "id": "0000000/insights/page_fan_adds/day",
             "name": "page_fan_adds",
             "period": "day",
             "values": [
                {
                   "value": 2,
                   "end_time": "2010-09-15T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                   "value": 0,
                   "end_time": "2010-09-16T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                   "value": 1,
                   "end_time": "2010-09-17T07:00:00+0000"
                }
             ],
             "description": "Daily New Likes of your Page (Total Count)"
          },
          {
             "id": "0000000/insights/page_fan_removes_unique/day",
             "name": "page_fan_removes_unique",
             "period": "day",
             "values": [
                {
                   "value": 0,
                   "end_time": "2010-09-15T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                   "value": 1,
                   "end_time": "2010-09-16T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                   "value": 0,
                   "end_time": "2010-09-17T07:00:00+0000"
                }
             ],
             "description": "Daily Unlikes of your Page (Unique Users)"
          },
          {
             "id": "0000000/insights/page_fan_removes/day",
             "name": "page_fan_removes",
             "period": "day",
             "values": [
                {
                   "value": 0,
                   "end_time": "2010-09-15T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                   "value": 1,
                   "end_time": "2010-09-16T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                   "value": 0,
                   "end_time": "2010-09-17T07:00:00+0000"
                }
             ],
             "description": "Daily Unlikes of your Page (Total Count)"
          },
          {
             "id": "0000000/insights/page_fan_adds_source_unique/day",
             "name": "page_fan_adds_source_unique",
             "period": "day",
             "values": [
                {
                   "value": {
                      "fan_box": 1,
                      "fan_page": 1
                   },
                   "end_time": "2010-09-15T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                   "value": [

                   ],
                   "end_time": "2010-09-16T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                   "value": {
                      "fan_page": 1
                   },
                   "end_time": "2010-09-17T07:00:00+0000"
                }
             ],
             "description": "Daily Users can like your page in many different places, both within Facebook and on other websites.  These are the most common places where users like your Page. (Unique Users)"
          },
```

The problem is that on the last result the value changes from

```
 "value": 0,
```

to

```
 "value": {
            "fan_box": 1,
            "fan_page": 1
          },
```

Also, the order of the returned JSON might be changed...

As such, I'm not sure how to go about serializing this... Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserializeobject.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you are typring to parse is of objects

your deserialization code will change to

```
result = ser.Deserialize<List<Library.Libraries.Model.Post>>(responseFromServer);
```

regarding the **value** thing can you share class definition of **Library.Libraries.Model.Post**?